# Error "must exist" - on creating register on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm creating a teacher that have one contact.

Here is the teacher model.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Teacher do
  permit_params :name, :contact_id

form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys

    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :contact_id, :as => :select, :collection => Contact.all.collect {|contact| [contact.email] }
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
```

Here is the contact model.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Contact do
  permit_params :phone, :email
end
```

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_11_12_175353) do

  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "namespace"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "resource_type"
    t.integer "resource_id"
    t.string "author_type"
    t.integer "author_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id"
    t.index ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace"
    t.index ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id"
  end

  create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admin_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "phone"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "teacher_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["teacher_id"], name: "index_groups_on_teacher_id"
  end

  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "teacher_id"
    t.integer "contact_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["contact_id"], name: "index_students_on_contact_id"
    t.index ["teacher_id"], name: "index_students_on_teacher_id"
  end

  create_table "subjects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "teacher_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["teacher_id"], name: "index_subjects_on_teacher_id"
  end

  create_table "teachers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "contact_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["contact_id"], name: "index_teachers_on_contact_id"
  end

end
```

I'm having a "Contact must exist" error, even with the contact data displaying in the teacher view.

I'm running rails 5.2, ruby 2.4 and using the active admin and wicked_pdf if relevant, sqlite database.

Already tried to follow the solution https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24518 but it don't works at all, it returns another error.

Answer (score 2):

in your `Teacher` model add

`belongs_to :contact, optional: true`

Comment: While I'm not doubting the validity of your answer (not my field of expertise), it would be an even better answer if you offered some explanatory text.